# Hangman string char StringBuilder

Tags: c#

I'm doing a raw hangman text game as a speedy coding exercise. Right now, my *blanks* should turn into correctly-chosen letters, while leaving underscores as placeholders for other letters, but instead, all of my *blanks* are being converted to the currently-selected, correct letter. Eg, if my word (*wordDisp*) is 'bag' and I guess 'a', all my blanks turn to 'a'; instead of the desired output of '_ a _'.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class Hang {
  public static string blanks = "_";
  public static string hangParts = "_____,|___|,  |  ,  O  , /|\\ , / \\ ";
  public static int tries = 0;
  public static void PrintHang(){
    Console.WriteLine("What's your word? ");
    string wordDisp = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] charDisp = wordDisp.ToCharArray();
    string stringDisp = charDisp.ToString();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    for(var i=0; i<charDisp.Length;i++){
       temp.Append(blanks);
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(charDisp.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(temp);

    while(tries < 6){

      for(var s=0;tries<6; s++){
        Console.WriteLine("What's your letter? ");
        var pick = Console.ReadLine();
        if(charDisp[s].ToString().Contains(pick)){
          temp.Replace(temp[s],Convert.ToChar(pick));
          Console.WriteLine(temp);
        }
        else{
          tries++;
          Console.WriteLine(hangParts[s]);
        }
      }
    }

  }


}

class Prog{
  public static void Main(){
    Hang.PrintHang();
  }
}
```

Comment: `for speed` is an odd objective. I _guarantee_ you any performance tweaks you make will be absolutely dwarfed by the interaction with the `Console`.

Comment: When you debugged through it, line by line, where did the code do something different to what you expected?

Comment: `while(tries < 6){

      for(var s=0;tries<6; s++){` Please explain what those two lines are _trying_ to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `temp.Replace(temp[s],Convert.ToChar(pick))`  you're replacing underscore with 1st char of string from Console.ReadLine() but temp starts with all chars as underscore.   So every letter is set to 1st letter of your input.

You'll need to map the index position of each letter in the target string in some way.  You'll also need to account for the input string having multiple letters that are the same "hello" for example with 2 'l'.

Then you can replace your underscore with the correct letter based on the index in the target string.

Couple other things...

You probably don't need the char array.  You can do the contains directly with the string wordDisp.Contains(pick).

Also you've got an error in how you're using "tries".  You should take out the "for" loop and just exit after a certain number of "misses".  You also need to account for the user having successfully matched all the letters - print something to let them know they matched it and then exit.